# Apigility+Doctrine: how to return a paginated collection

Tags: php, pagination, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

I´ve manage to install Apigility + Doctrine and to return results of single entities (/service/x_id) and collections (/service), this works out of the box with no modifications.

I am now in the phase of returning filtered results based on URL parameters.

I can retrieve the url parameters and I can retrieve filtered results. To do this, I extended fetch*() methods in my own ResourceClass. It works fine but this result is not paginated and not in the same HAL / Json format as the other responses (the out-of-the-box responses). I am returning the result of `getEntityManager('my.em.name')->getRepository(my.repo.name)->findBy($params)` and it actually looks like this:

```
    {
"_links":
{
    "self":
    {
        "href": "http://api.local/service?startcode=7531"
    }
},
"_embedded":
{
    "objektprojectstart":
    [
        {
            "oid": 14427,
            "opsId": 3760,
            "startcode": "7531",
            "tid": 44798,
            "_links":
            {
                "self":
                {
                    "href": "http://studoraapi.local/service/3760"
                }
            }
        },
        {... more},
```

What is the correct solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: In what way is the response not the same? Please be more specific about what the differences are between the response that you got and the one that you want.

Comment: The format is not the same, in a proper HAL response, you see the total count, links, page and so on, like this:

`{"_links": { "self":
            {"href": "..."},
            "first":{"href": "..."},
            "last":{"href": "..."}},
        "_embedded": {
            "objektprojectstart":
            [ { "oid": 14473,"opsId": 3791,"startcode": "7531", "tid": 44845, }]
        },
        "page_count": 1,
        "page_size": 25,
        "total_items": 1,
        "page": 1
    }` (sorry the format) So the question is basically why this happens and how to fix it, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a response with pagination you will have to make sure that you return a Zend `Paginator` instance from your `fetch` method.

In the Apigility documents **[here](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service#service-classes)** it is written as follows:

> A Collection class which extends `Zend\Paginator\Paginator`, which will allow you to provide paginated result sets.